# Limit of Functions from $\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have any function $f:\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Would it be possible to state that if  $\forall m \in \mathbb{R}, \lim_{(x, mx) \to (x_{0}, y_{0})} = L$, then the $\lim_ {(x, y) \to (x_{0}, y_{0})}$ exists and equals $L$?

My initial intuition was that approaching through any line would be somewhat equivalent to approaching through any path, since every path would be approximatelly linear around a sufficiently small distance of $(x_{0}, y_{0})$.

Comment: Every path is not approximately linear because we're not assuming anything about the paths except their convergence to $(x_0,y_0)$. Furthermore, even if every path is approximately linear around a small distance of $(x_0,y_0)$, the nature of that approximation will depend on how $f$ behaves around $(x_0,y_0)$, and I don't think that dependence is so small that you can ignore it. Having said that, I feel like, given enough regularity of $f$ around $(x_0,y_0)$ , your statement could be true. You can try and find sufficient conditions.

Comment: What do you mean?  If $(x, mx) \to (x_0, y_0)$, then $x \to x_0$, so $m x \to m x_0$.  But that can't be $y_0$ for **all** $m \in \mathbb R$ unless $x_0 = 0$ and $y_0 = 0$.
Are you talking about $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x,mx)$?

Comment: If so, a counterexample would be $f(x,y) = 0$ if $x\ne 0$, but $f(0,y) =1$.